# How we can return a variable which is declared globally in a function?

Tags: sql, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo7()
RETURNS DOUBLE
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
DECLARE age INTEGER;
begin
age:=55;
return age;
END;
$$
```

when I return this an error is showing can anybody help me in this?

```
syntax error line 2 at position 8 unexpected 'age'. (line 126)
```

this error is showing

Comment: are you sure that you want to use a function? It will work like that if you create a procedure like ```create or replace procedure demo7() ...``` then you call it like ```call demo7()```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake (SQL) Scripting does not support functions. You can use Snowflake Scripting to write stored procedures and procedural code outside of a stored procedure:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demo7()
RETURNS DOUBLE
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
DECLARE age INTEGER;
begin
age:=55;
return age;
END;
$$;
```